# Dictionary multiple in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a multidictionary:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': '2'}}},
 'b': {'b': {'c': {'d': '7'}}},
 'c': {'b': {'c': {'d': '3'}}},
 'f': {'d': {'c': {'d': '1'}}}}
```

How can I sort it based on the values `'2' '3' '7' '1'`
so my output will be:

```
f.d.c.d.1
a.b.c.d.2
c.b.c.d.3
b.b.c.d.7
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `f.d.c.d`, `a.b.c.d`, etc. as keys? What's the point of all this nesting?

Comment: What have you tried? (And how did you come by such a convoluted structure?)

Comment: You need to figure out what you actually [need to do](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 3):

You've got a fixed-shape structure, which is pretty simple to sort:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': '2'}}}, 'c': {'b': {'c': {'d': '3'}}}, 'b': {'b': {'c': {'d': '7'}}}, 'f': {'d': {'c': {'d': '1'}}}}
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x].values()[0].values()[0].values()[0])
['f', 'a', 'c', 'b']
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].values()[0].values()[0].values()[0])
[('f', {'d': {'c': {'d': '1'}}}),
 ('a', {'b': {'c': {'d': '2'}}}),
 ('c', {'b': {'c': {'d': '3'}}}),
 ('b', {'b': {'c': {'d': '7'}}})]
```

Yes, this is a bit ugly and clumsy, but only because your structure is inherently ugly and clumsy.

In fact, other than the fact that `d['f']` has a key `'d'` instead of `'b'`, it's even more straightforward. I suspect that may be a typo, in which case things are even easier:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': '2'}}}, 'c': {'b': {'c': {'d': '3'}}}, 'b': {'b': {'c': {'d': '7'}}}, 'f': {'b': {'c': {'d': '1'}}}}
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]['b']['c']['d'])
[('f', {'b': {'c': {'d': '1'}}}),
 ('a', {'b': {'c': {'d': '2'}}}),
 ('c', {'b': {'c': {'d': '3'}}}),
 ('b', {'b': {'c': {'d': '7'}}})]
```

As others have pointed out, this is almost certainly not the right data structure for whatever it is you're trying to do. But, if it is, this is how to deal with it.

PS, it's confusing to call this a "multidictionary". That term usually means "dictionary with potentially multiple values per key" (a concept which in Python you'd probably implement as a `defaultdict` with `list` or `set` as its default). A single, single-valued dictionary that happens to contain dictionaries is better named a "nested dictionary".

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this kind of design is very hard to read and maintain. Can you consider replacing the internal dictionaries with string-names?

E.g.:

```
mydict = {
    'a.b.c.d' : 2,
    'b.b.c.d' : 7,
    'c.b.c.d' : 3,
    'f.d.c.d' : 1,
}
```

This one is much easier to sort and waaaay more readable.

Now, a dictionary is something unsortable due to its nature. Thus, you have to sort an e.g. a list representation of it:

```
my_sorted_dict_as_list = sorted(mydict.items(), 
                                key=lambda kv_pair: kv_pair[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it recursively:

```
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': '2'}}}, 'c': {'b': {'c': {'d': '3'}}}, 'b': {'b': {'c': {'d': '7'}}}, 'f': {'d': {'c': {'d': '1'}}}}

def nested_to_string(item):

    if hasattr(item, 'items'):
        out = ''
        for key in item.keys():
            out += '%s.' % key + nested_to_string(item[key])
        return out
    else:
        return item + '\n'

print nested_to_string(d)
```

or

```
def nested_to_string(item):
    def rec_fun(item, temp, res):
        if hasattr(item, 'items'):
            for key in item.keys():
                temp += '%s.' % key
                rec_fun(item[key], temp, res)
                temp = ''
        else:
            res.append(temp + item)

    res = []
    rec_fun(d, '', res)
    return res
```

why do you want to do this.

Comment: hi, i tried this but it doesent' work.. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is basically a multi-level tree, so a good way to do what you want is to do what is called a depth-first traversal of it, which can be done recursively, and then massage the intermediate results a bit to sort and format them them into the desired format.

```
multidict = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': '2'}}},
             'b': {'b': {'c': {'d': '7'}}},
             'c': {'b': {'c': {'d': '3'}}},
             'f': {'d': {'c': {'d': '1'}}}}

def nested_dict_to_string(nested_dict):
    chains = []
    for key,value in nested_dict.items():
        chains.append([key] + visit(value))
    chains = ['.'.join(chain) for chain in sorted(chains, key=lambda chain: chain[-1])]
    return '\n'.join(chains)

def visit(node):
    result = []
    try:
        for key,value in node.items():
            result += [key] + visit(value)
    except AttributeError:
        result = [node]
    return result

print nested_dict_to_string(multidict)
```

Output:

```
f.d.c.d.1
a.b.c.d.2
c.b.c.d.3
b.b.c.d.7
```